# Taking input and redirecting it to an emulated rom (Twitch Plays Pokemon)

Tags: emulation

So if anyone has been following Twitch Plays Pokemon for the last week or so (http://www.twitch.tv/twitchplayspokemon) you'll know what I'm talking about. They are streaming an emulated version of Pokemon Red and allowing members to type controls into the chat. The controls they type correspond to that on an actual gameboy and are somehow 'sent' to the emulator as controls. For example, if someone types 'start' it pops up the start menu in the game.

Is there any documentation online which could show me how to do something like this (albeit smaller scale)?

Thanks!

Comment: +1. Would love to make one myself, but not sure that I'm that far along in my programming experiences.

Comment: made one in node using xdotool for linux/mac and pywin for windows here https://github.com/eltacodeldiablo/TwitchPlaysX

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple once you get the hang of emulating keystrokes.

On windows you can use the [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI to simulate keystrokes, here's some example c++ code that holds down the A key for 150 milliseconds:

```
keybd_event(0x41, 0, 0, 0); // starts holding down key 0x41 (A)
Sleep(150);
keybd_event(0x41, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // releases key 0x41 (A)
```

(you can find values for other keys [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Once you get keystroke emulation working, you just need to either make your software connect to the IRC channel of your twitch chat or run HexChat or any other IRC client, make it connect to the twitch chat by following [this guide](http://teamfortress.tv/forum/thread/719-tutorial-connecting-to-twitch-tv-via-xchat-mirc/1), enabling logging and parsing the chat log on your software by simply reading the file line by line and waiting for new lines once you get to the end of it.

I wrote my own Twitch Plays ... software on Windows in c# in a matter of minutes and then released a polished, configurable version that should work on any game [here](https://github.com/Francesco149/OpenTwitchPlays).